# Set FAB icon color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

[image: current fab]
*current FAB*

I would like to know how to change the icon color of the FAB (Floating Action Button) widget supplied by the 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' library from green to white.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
<color name="color_primary">#00B33C</color>
<color name="color_primary_dark">#006622</color>
<color name="accent">#FFB366</color>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

If you are using `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`, use `app:tint`

```xml
app:tint="@android:color/white"
```

**UPDATE**

Refer to the answer of @Saleem Khan which is the standard way to set the `app:tint` using:

```xml
android:tint="@android:color/white"
```

via XML on `FloatingActionButton`.

**OLD (June 2015)**

This answer was written before October 2015, when `android:tint` on `FloatingActionButton` was supported only with API >= 21.

You can change it programmatically using `ColorFilter`.

```
//get the drawable
Drawable myFabSrc = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
//copy it in a new one
Drawable willBeWhite = myFabSrc.getConstantState().newDrawable();
//set the color filter, you can use also Mode.SRC_ATOP
willBeWhite.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
//set it to your fab button initialized before
myFabName.setImageDrawable(willBeWhite);
```

Comment: It works when setting `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` and using `Drawable myFabSrc = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_input_add, getTheme());`

Comment: Your solution is too complicated. Just use android:tint="@android:color/white"

Comment: It's not complicated @MahdiElMasaoudi. Sometimes and most of the times there are use cases where it has to be programatically be updated! It's upto the user to reduce the overheads as much as possible.

Comment: If you use `FloatingActionButton` that in `com.google.android.material` package, you should add `app:tint` instead of `android:tint`.

Comment: use `app:tint="@android:color/white"`

Comment: I'm updating the answer with these info.

Answer (score 200):

Using android:tint property you can set the color like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
   />
```

Comment: such a clean solution

Comment: `android:tint` appears to be only supported in API level 21 and above :( https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html

Comment: @alexbirkett except FloatingActionButton is part of the support library here, and seems to implement it on older APIs as well (tried it with API 16).

Comment: in google material  android:tint well not word, replace it with app:tint

Answer (score 140):

If you are using `Material Components`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:tint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google"/>
```

If you want to use icon default color, change `app:tint="@null"`

Comment: Used the `app:backgroundTint=""` for the background color and `app:tint=""` for the image tint.

Comment: I looked for about 30 minutes until I realized it shouldn't be `android:tint` but rather `app:tint` .

Comment: 'app:tint="@null"' save my day :)

Answer (score 45):

You have to change `app:tint` for that to work. `android:tint` didn't do any change for me.

Answer (score 28):

It's easier than get the drawables, you only need to access to the color filter and set it to the color that you want.

```
FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myfabid);

myFab.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: I don't know why it has been down voted, this is the correct solution and should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Use this in a fragment `yourFab.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));`

Comment: how to set FAB color in xml or style?

Comment: @roghayehhosseini `android:tint` for API 21 and above. It also works if you use the support library `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`

Comment: Use app:tint to support APIs below 21

Comment: Neither app:tint nor android:tint worked for me but this did. UP VOTED!

Answer (score 14):

Since `FloatingActionButton` extends `ImageView` we can use `ImageViewCompat` to tint the icon:

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(
    floatingActionButton,
    ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE)
);
```

Comment: This is working and one of the best way to do it through code if you want to toggle the icon color! Thanks!

Comment: I tried with setImageResource with the same drawable with a different color but didn't workout. This was the best way for me

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had to change the fab icon and it's color during on click of it.

Answer (score 7):

Use the white version of [ic_add](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_add) from the google design site.

`android:tint` looks like a clean solution but it is not supported below API level 21

Using a bitmap adds less complexity to your app than attempting to change the color of an existing icon programmatically. Less complexity means fewer things to test :)

Comment: It seems to me as if `android:tint` works for the `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` defined in the support library even on lower API level devices, I've just tested it on a JellyBean image (API 16).

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:backgroundTint="@color/sm_blue"
       app:tint="@color/white"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using material FAB  use app:tint to change the color of the icon instead of android:tint

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the color of the icon in CollapsingToolbarLayout use the following code

`app:tint="@color/white"`

Use the app instead of Android

Answer (score 3):

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_loan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/ci_blue"
    android:theme="@style/fabtheme"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:rippleColor="@color/white" />
```

theme

```
<style name="fabtheme" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

or

use the attribute

app:tint="@color/white"

Answer (score 3):

**For API >= 21**

My Solution to change `FloatingActionButton` icon color programmatically

```
val fab = FloatingActionButton(requireContext())
fab.apply {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your custom style:

```
<style name="FloatingButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Where colorSecondary is the background and colorOnSecondary is the color of the drawable of the button.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
            android:theme="@style/FloatingButton" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`

Then

1. To change **Background Color** of Floating Action Button, use `app:backgroundTint`
2. To change Floating Action Button's **Icon's color**, use `app:tint`
3. To change Floating Action Button's **Icon Drawable**, use `app:srcCompat`

   ```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fb_icon"
    app:tint="@android:color/black" />
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Extended**, set `app:iconTint` you can do like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:icon="@drawable/d0"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Material3.FloatingActionButton"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This will keep the original color of the icon.

```
app:tint="@null"
```

or

```
android:tint="@null"
```

Answer (score 1):

To changing the background of fab(floating action button) add this line in xml file (in floating action button part) :

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_primary60"
```

in this code i use "material_dynamic_primary60" color. But we can use any color in color file.

to changing color of floating action buttons icon:

```
app:tint="@color/white"
```

and this is how it is will gonna look [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xu24.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using material FAB, you can style it programmatically using the below code in Kotlin.

```
fab.supportImageTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.fab_icon_tint)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java

```
private FloatingActionButton login;
login = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);  
login.setColorFilter(android.R.color.white);
```

In XML

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:src="@drawable/loginicon"
    app:rippleColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pass_l" />
```