# Change FAB text color in android

Tags: android

I am able to change the color of the FAB but I couldn't change the color of the text. The icon that I am using is white but it is shown as black. Please see my xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time"
            android:tint="@android:color/white" />
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set FAB icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113819/set-fab-icon-color)

Comment: ^ The accepted answer there has the right suggestion. For future reference, material.io has docs for all of the Material Components widgets, and tables that show which XML attributes to use for what; e.g, https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#regular-fabs.

Comment: I don't know what's happening but somehow I still can't get the white text. Please see my edit.

Comment: You want `app:tint` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31114037.

Answer (score 0):

Use **app:tint** to change the tint of icon. You can achieve required output by using the code below.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time"
            app:tint="@android:color/white" />
```